# "Mean absolute error time series data matrix"

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time-series data matrix of order **row=24** and **column=2192**, where each column is a single day of 24 observations(24 hours a day). Then, I split the matrix into two parts suppose the first matrix is **A**  of order **row=24** and **column=1827** and the second matrix is **B** of order **row=24** and **column=365**. suppose the first column of the **B** matrix is Sunday, Know I
extract all the Sunday columns from the **A** matrix. Then I calculate the mean absolute error(MAE) from each column of matrix **A** with the first column (Sunday) of the matrix **B**, for example, columns of matrix **A** is denoted by  **(c1,c8,...,c190)** and the first column of the **B** matrix is **d1**. One way to deal with such a problem is to take each column of the Sunday from the **A** matrix which is **(c1,c8,...,c290)**  with the first column of the second matrix and calculating **MAE** each time. and repeat the process for the last column(which is **c290**) of the **A** matrix. Then choosing the minimum **MAE** to value from all **MAE** is the forecast for Monday.

```
C1 <- as.vector(c1)
D1<- as.vector(d1)
mea1 <- mean(abs(C1,D1))
C8<- as.vector(c8)
mae<- mean(abs(C8,D1))
```

While doing this for seven days of the week in a similar way. But such a task manually doing is difficult and time-consuming. Please suggest any alternative method which saves time and energy.

Comment: Welcome. Please share your data using ``dput()`` rather than describing it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your interest I  am new in r can you guide me how to write in `dput()`

Comment: I tried to solve your another similar question, but this one is not clear?